# Safari window always highlight

Tags: mac, safari, windows, tabs, highlights

Is there a way to have a Safari window (or just a tab) **always highlighted**?

I mean, when using other programs, have a piece of screen occupied by a Safari window (resized, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) or [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which one do you think is better? Thank you very much for your answer, u got the point. That was what i was lookin for